# How do I make an EF-Core (2.1) Compiled Query return an IQueryable?

Tags: linq, iqueryable, ef-core-2.1

I've been trying to convert a query that gets executed a lot in my application to a compiled query, with no success. I've boiled it down to a simple query so have concluded that I must be misunderstanding how something works.

Here is the simple example query without using compile query (this works):

```
private static Func<Entities, int, string, IQueryable<Users>> _getUsers =
    (Entities context) =>
        from au in context.Users select au;
```

Once I add the compile query call:

```
private static Func<Entities, int, string, IQueryable<Users>> _getUsers =
    EF.CompileQuery((Entities context) =>
        from au in context.Users select au);
```

I get this exception:

> Cannot implicitly convert type `System.Func<Entities, int, string, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Users>>` to `System.Func<Entities, int, string, System.Linq.IQueryable<Users>>`. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

For the life of me, I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong...any suggestions?

Comment: Compiling means creating the SQL query and reusing it. Applying *more* LINQ operators to that query would mean *re*compiling it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> How do I make an EF-Core (2.1) Compiled Query return an IQueryable?

You can't. All `EF.Compile` methods return either `IEnumerable<TResult>` or `TResult`, and the corresponding `Async` methods return respectively `AsyncEnumerable<TResult>` or `Task<TResult>`.

As you can see, there no `IQueryable<T>` returning methods. In other words, the compiled queries are supposed to be final (non composable) - the overloads allow you to pass the necessary arguments.

I can't say exactly why is that. The explanation for the [Explicitly Compiled Queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-2.0#explicitly-compiled-queries) in the EF Core documentation is:

> Although in general EF Core can automatically compile and cache queries based on a hashed representation of the query expressions, this mechanism can be used to obtain a small performance gain by bypassing the computation of the hash and the cache lookup, allowing the application to use an already compiled query through the invocation of a delegate.

Looks like the idea is to not only cache the `IQueryable` expression tree, but also skip the transformation of the expression tree to whatever data structure they use internally.

Comment: I'd say this makes sense. EF Core's compilation step produces SQL. Once you have that SQL statement you can't apply more Queryable operators to it without having to *re*compile the result into SQL.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I'm not quite sure it's SQL, especially taking into account the client/mixed evaluation. But for sure is some AST or similar structure specific for the execution of the query.

Comment: Thanks. I was confused because I saw an example that had IQueryable as the return value.

Comment: @jceddy did you get any benefit by doing this? There are a lot of discussions on this over the internet. So it confuses me a little. Though for some cases it executes faster than without external compilation and in some cases it is slower.

Answer (score -1):

You can only return IEnumerable Type, but you can trigger it with AsQueryable.

Comment: You'd gain nothing by that.